# Custom modification of Related Post plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

I am supporting a website running on Wordpress 3.8 with a wpzoom theme (zenko)  on top of that with most of the articles posts  running  on multiple pages. 
For pagination navigation we use the WP-PageNavi plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ with the function 
`<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) ); ?>`
inserted in the single.php code after the 
`<?php the_content(); ?>`   function.
Recently we added the WordPress Related Posts http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-23-related-posts-plugin/ . However when activated the related posts appear before the page navigation links- buttons and I would prefer to change it to appear after them. 
Looking around in the related post plugin's code I found the corresponding formating code as follows:

```
global $wp_rp_output;
$wp_rp_output = array();
function wp_rp_add_related_posts_hook($content) {
global $wp_rp_output, $post;

$options = wp_rp_get_options();

if ($content != "" && $post->post_type === 'post' && (($options["on_single_post"] && is_single()) || (is_feed() && $options["on_rss"]))) {
    if (!isset($wp_rp_output[$post->ID])) {
        $wp_rp_output[$post->ID] = wp_rp_get_related_posts();
    }
    $content = str_replace('%RELATEDPOSTS%', '', $content); // used for gp
    $content = $content . $wp_rp_output[$post->ID];
}

return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_rp_add_related_posts_hook', 10);
```

My question is how can I modify the code so that the array of related post appear after the page navigation links

Comment: Try changing the priority from 10 to 99 in `add_filter(...)`

Comment: Tried it but did not worked. Thank you for your suggestion !